# What is the Equivalent Shell Command for os.chdir('/path/to/dir') in Databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

What is equivalent shell command for `os.chdir('/path/to/dir')` in Databricks?

I have tried the following,

```
%fs cd /data_platform/ccs/src/

%sh cd /data_platform/ccs/src/
```

None of them seem to work.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do by navigating to that particular path?

Comment: I have a Python egg file that is stored in DBFS. I want to be able to extract and install it as a package on my cluster. However, I want to put these commands in an init script to be executed through a Databricks activity in my ADF pipeline. That is why I am looking for shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have a similar function in the `dbutils` file system package. Normally databricks works under the file system `/dbfs` scope by default and you can create new folders there. Probably you will need to leverage the python `os` module in order to achieve the change in the current working directory. In any case, try the code below to check all available file system functions.

```
dbutils.fs.help()
```